# jQuery - Getting the text value of a table cell in the same row as a clicked element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I click a link in a table cell. I need to get the value of a specific cell within this same table row.

```
<tr>
    <td class="one">this</td>
    <td class="two">that</td>
    <td class="three">here</td>
    <td class="four"><a href="#">there</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="one">qwqw</td>
    <td class="two">dfgh</td>
    <td class="three">ui</td>
<td class="four"><a href="#">there</a></td>
</tr>
```

I have a click handler attached to the link in the fourth cell. That click handler calls a function that opens a modal window. When a form in the modal is submitted I want to also pass the value of td class="two" from the row in which the link was clicked to this modal.

Here is the function that sends the modal (the problem area is getting the correct value for var Something):

```
var Send = function() {
    var Name = $( '#name' ).val();
    var Something = $(this).closest('td').siblings('.two').text(); // version 1. doesn't work
    var Something = $(this).closest('tr').siblings('td.two').text(); // version 2 also doesn't work
    var Something = $(this).attr('class'); // version 3. just a test but also doesn't work
    $.ajax( {
        async: false,
        data: { name: Name, somedata: Something },
        type: 'POST',
        url: the url
    });        
};
```

The problem is that I cannot get the correct value for Something. It should be the value of td class=two in the same row as the clicked element.

The way this all comes together is. Click the target link, that calls a method called Send_Click(). Send_Click does some validations and then calls Send() but the value for Something is never populated. Is this because `this` is not what I'm thinking it is? Hjelp!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You want `.children()` instead ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/children/)):

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td.two').text();
```

Comment: How can I use something like yours for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004056/how-to-retrieve-the-tr-data-on-the-same-row-within-gridview-using-jquery-modal-w (I have a link in the same row and display some data from another column in the same row.

Answer (score 69):

Nick has the right answer, but I wanted to add you could also get the cell data without needing the class name

```
var Something = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

`:eq(#)` has a zero based index ([link](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)).

Comment: How can I use something like yours for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004056/how-to-retrieve-the-tr-data-on-the-same-row-within-gridview-using-jquery-modal-w (I have a link in the same row and display some data from another column in the same row.

Comment: I was looking for this, it works great with jQuery Mobile, thanks!

Comment: i prefer this method as i like less dependencies and less code.

Answer (score 7):

it should work fine:

```
var Something = $(this).children("td:nth-child(n)").text();
```

Comment: How can I use something like yours for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004056/how-to-retrieve-the-tr-data-on-the-same-row-within-gridview-using-jquery-modal-w (I have a link in the same row and display some data from another column in the same row.

Answer (score 4):

so you can use parent() to reach to the parent tr and then use find to gather the td with class two

```
var Something = $(this).parent().find(".two").html();
```

or

```
var Something = $(this).parent().parent().find(".two").html();
```

use as much as parent() what ever the depth of the clicked object according to the tr row

hope this works...

Answer (score 4):

This will also work

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('td').text()
```