# How to retrieve the TR data on the same row within GridView using JQuery modal window

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I am trying to follow this link: [Link to Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-Row-details-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-in-ASPNet.aspx)

I have the following GridView in a SP Visual Web Part:

```
<asp:GridView ID="BookingResults" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="commHdr" Text="Show Guideline" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnShow3" CssClass="btnSearch3" Text="VIEW" PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);" OnClientClick="javascript:test();return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic" HeaderText="Topic" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Specialty" HeaderText="Specialty" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Provider Name">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <div style="width: 155px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
                       <asp:Label ID="lblEllipsis" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Provider") %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Provider") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </div>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>' CssClass="sumM"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Guideline" HeaderText="Guideline" ItemStyle-CssClass="gLine" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gLine" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

After the code is generated it looks like this on the webpage:

[image]

Each row has its own data and an example of generated HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <a onclick="javascript:test();return false;" id="ctl00_ctl33_g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9_BookingResults_ctl05_btnShow3" class="btnSearch3" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl33$g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9$BookingResults$ctl05$btnShow3&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;javascript:void(0);&quot;, false, true))">VIEW</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        After Hours
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        Pediatrics;
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="width: 155px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
            <span id="ctl00_ctl33_g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9_BookingResults_ctl05_lblEllipsis" title="All Providers;">
                All Providers;
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="sumM" valign="top">
        <span id="ctl00_ctl33_g_36ed1b14_1f08_43fb_8099_eb3423a33ed9_BookingResults_ctl05_Label1">
            <html>
                <p>
                    <span style="FONT-SIZE&#58;11pt;">Callback Number
                        <span id="ms-rterangepaste-end"></span>​
                    </span>
                </p>
            </html>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="gLine" valign="top"> <!-- HIDDEN FROM USER BUT IN SOURCE CODE -->
        <html>
            <p>
                THIS IS A TEST GUIDELINE BUT NOT SHOWN TO THE USER BUT WILL BE SHOWN IN THE MODEL WINDOW.
            </p>
        </html>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS to hide the column from view but still execute from code-behind:

```
.gLine {
    display: none;
}
```

Using the following to display the modal window:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    <b>Id:</b> <span id="infoShow"></span>
</div>
```

I am trying to display the data from row under the `Guideline` header respective to the link click by the following method in JQuery:

```
function test() {
    alert("test");
    $("#infoShow").html($(".gLine", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "View Guideline",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
}
```

In the example above, when I click VIEW link, the modal window should display:

```
<HTML>
     <p>
     THIS IS A TEST GUIDELINE BUT NOT SHOWN TO THE USER BUT WILL BE SHOWN IN THE MODEL WINDOW.
     </p>
</HTML>
```

but it is displaying nothing.

How do I modify my JQuery code to show the text inside the TD with class `gLine`

I tried the below as well but I keep getting `undefined` for the second alert:

```
function test() {
    alert("test");
    $("#infoShow").html($(".gLine", $(this).closest("tr")).html());

    var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    alert(tableData[5]);
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "View Guideline",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `<html>` tags anywhere inside your main `<html>` tags that wrap everything.

Comment: They are all entered with data, so I will decode it and then show in the display window.

Comment: It's not valid HTML, the browser and/or jQuery may not interpret it correctly.

Comment: What if I wanted to show it as IS?

Comment: You could put it into an iframe, I guess.

Comment: How can I do that? Even if there is a dummy window that pops up without URL bar just so it doesn't look like its a Window, that would be fine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can make your demo work:

First, remove the `<html>` tags from your markup.

Second remove the `onclick="javascript:test();return false;"` from your links

Lastly, change your code to this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4116/)):

```
$(function () {

    $('table a').click(function () {

        $("#infoShow").html($(".gLine", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "View Guideline",
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    });

});
```

Please note that when you use jQuery UI, include the appropriate version of jQuery.

---

Edit: The reason why the code in the question doesn't work is because the `onclick` is calling `test()` without any reference to the element. If it looked like this:

```
onclick="javascript:test(this);return false;"
```

then the test function could have done this:

```
function test(element) {
    // ...
    $("#infoShow").html($(".gLine", $(element).closest("tr")).html());
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Later jQuery? Try it out and see if it works; it works in that demo.

Comment: Now sure what I was doing wrong but copying you worked... Now how can I display HTML genearated text as is without showing the HTML tags?

Comment: Try asking that in a separate question, I have no idea how to use asp.net

Comment: Already on it. I totally forgot to UPVOTE :) Thank you. Can accept it in 10 minutes... So far so good!

Comment: I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007291/how-to-display-html-generated-text-instead-of-the-tags (if you are interested to take a look)