# getting values from a specific row in a table in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a table that sort of looks like this:

```
{{#each names}}
...
<td id="fullNameID">{{fullName}}</td>
<td>{{otherFields}}</td>
...
{{/each}}
```

I also have a delete button as one of the  against each row. How exactly do I get the fullName that is displayed in that row?

I tried something like

```
 $('#userRoleTable #fullNameID').text());
```

However, every row's fullName is being picked up. (Eg. name1name2name3...)

Comment: You want to get fullName when click delete button?

Comment: It really doesn't matter what it returns, I need something unique that represents the row so that I may use that ID to delete it. Let's go with fullName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate. The same question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315600/jquery-getting-the-text-value-of-a-table-cell-in-the-same-row-as-a-clicked-ele).

However, the answer you are looking for is probably:

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td#fullNameID').text();
```

This assumes that your table cells are inside the same row as the delete button.

Comment: Also, you should probably change the id on the `fullNameID` cell to a class if you are using it more than once on each page.