# How to enable Dropdownlist by Checkbox in multirow table using JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, html-select

I want to control [the dropdownlist to be enabled when the checkbox is checked by respective rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD5y6.png)
My current progress I manage to enable and disable the dropdownlist but its not controlled by the respective rows.

Whenever the checkbox is checked, all dropdownlist were enabled.

the php code is partly from html:

```
<td>
    <select class="selection" name="lotDist[]" > 
    <option></option>';

    ==== sql queries in here ====

    while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '
        <option value="'.$row["LotNo"].' / '.$row2["Grouping"].' - '.$row2["InBulkForm"].'"> 
        '.$row2["Grouping"].' - '.$row2["InBulkForm"].'</option> ';
    }  
    echo '
    </select>
</td>
<td>'.$row["LoadingWeek"].'</td>
<td>                   
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="chkBox" name="cBox[]" value="'.$row["LotNo"].'" '.$check.'>
</td>



<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selection').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        var $checkBox = $('.chkBox');

        $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
            //get the previous element to us, which is the select
            var $select = $('.selection')

            if (this.checked) {
                $select.removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. You will need to be more specific on your selectors. At the moment you are saying when I click any checkbox with this class `chkbox` then activate any dropdown with this class `selection`. I think you only want to enable the dropdown in the same row as the chkbox . Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315600/jquery-getting-the-text-value-of-a-table-cell-in-the-same-row-as-a-clicked-ele which will help you select only the items in the same row

Comment: thanks man.. the title search didnt bring me there..hihi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$(this).closest('tr').find('.selection');` you can find the corresponding select box the belongs to the row of the changed checkbox.

The `closest()` function finds the first parent that matches the selector. Since you are using a table we can select the row with the `tr` selector and find the corresponding select element within the row.

Also changed the way the select box is enabled and disabled. It's better to change the property then the attribute. and code is shorter too. However your method works as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selection').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  var $checkBox = $('.chkBox');

  $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
    var $select = $(this).closest('tr').find('.selection');

    $select.prop('disabled', !this.checked);

    /* This works too but its better to change the property and the code is shorter when using the this.checked boolean.
    
    if (this.checked) {
      $select.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="selection" name="lotDist[]">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>week</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="chkBox" name="cBox[]" value="'.$row[" LotNo "].'" '.$check.'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="selection" name="lotDist[]">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>week</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="chkBox" name="cBox[]" value="'.$row[" LotNo "].'" '.$check.'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that's amazing man.. thanks a lot.. now its worked like charm!!